# TFS 2012 Version Tree - ClearCase like?

Tags: version-control, tfs

Are there any tools within TFS 2012 that allow a ClearCase like graphical version tree for a given file? Based on Googling and my experimentation, it seems the version tree capabilities within TFS 2012 are all around change sets. What branch a change set was created on, where it was merged, etc. This is not granular enough though. A lot of times a developer sees a piece of code in a file and wants to know where it came from. ClearCase's version tree was ideal for this.

In TFS 2012 (and probably 2010) you can view the history of a file on a branch (i.e. main) and it will textually show all the change sets for that file and what branches the merges came from. This seems to be basically the version tree in ClearCase, but in text form. Are there any third party tools to convert this history into graphical form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no ClearCase like version tree provided by Microsoft.

There are two graphical reprensetation available in Visual Studio.

1. Branch Tree : Right Click on Branch > Branches > View Hierarchy
2. Track ChangeSet: Right Click on file or folder > View History > select changeset and Right Click > Track ChangeSet

In Addition there is paid (trial available) version tree extension available for VS2012 and VS2013.

Check this link out http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e0c5cd21-1371-4032-84f3-8a2be88e2875

It does work as ClearCase Version tree and allows you to trace change set throuh merges and search changeset by labels etc.

Thanks,
TFSExtensions.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nice [gitk](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gitk/info) tool in combination with X11 in [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and with [git-tf](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-tf/info) or [git-tf](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-tfs/info) (e.g. this is not a 1-click solution).

In some ways gitk is not as good as the clearcase version tree, you can for instance not move and hide/display (parts of) branches, but on the other hand I love the instant inline diff view it provides.